# Disabling original key function for hotkeys

Tags: teamspeak, autohotkey

This question is directly related to teamspeak and gaming, but, could be expanded to broader fields, but, I wasn't able to find much regarding hotkeys except for here in the Arqade, hence my asking here. (other places I've looked were general Google searches, and searches on superuser as that's what I thought would be most relevant)

In teamspeak, I have bound my right alt to talk and menu key to switch channel. The issue arises though when the game (or w/e other application) I'm in also do things with these keys.

In short, I would like to have left alt remain as left alt, but, have right alt and menu key to only serve as a teamspeak hotkey, and have no input be sent to any other application. The only solution that comes close to solving this issue in my own research is autohotkey, but I've not actually found a solution yet. (the answer doesn't have to be an autohotkey script, but from my understanding, that's probably in the vicinity of the simplest solution, I could be wrong.)

Comment: This should be possible with autohotkey, but I've been having a bit of trouble getting it to work reliably with Mumble on my machine, which is why I use macro keys on my keyboard.  It might be partially because I'm defining 2 hotkeys in one file, but the overall trick is to issue an esoteric hotkey that no other global hotkey listener, nor any active application, will catch.

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting and failing at using autohotkey to achieve this, I stumbled across a request link on TeamSpeak's forums which asked for an equivalent to Ventrilo's 'discard' key. This request was made several years back, so, I decided to search the options for it.

Under TeamSpeak 3 > settings > options > hotkeys
first I had to change the dropdown on the bottom right from "Default" to "Keyboard and Mouse Only"
then, after right-clicking the hotkey in question and clicking "Edit Hotkey"
There was now a new "discard" checkbox. Checking that by itself didn't fix it though, since the detected keybind is apparently different. After having changed the setting from "default" to "keyboard and mouse only", new hotkey binds are appended with "(Keyboard)", so I rebound to get that binding.

After applying these new settings, the original keyboard input is successfully "discarded," with no functions of the original keys being passed through to underlying applications.